# Using "ProGuarded" library in "ProGuarded" app fails. Non-ProGuard app or lib works fine

Tags: java, android, proguard

I have a library that has been optimized and obfuscated with ProGuard, and it works fine if I do not use ProGuard on the app. That is, I can see it making HTTP requests to the correct places and it causes the app to respond properly to certain touch events. Similarly, if I use ProGuard on the app but NOT the library, everything still works fine. I only encounter issues when both the lib and app have been "ProGuarded" separately, where the app/library no longer make any HTTP requests. Why do I encounter problems in this "double ProGuard" situation? I'm beginning to wonder if there might be class naming collisions and the library is just calling the wrong class.

My ProGuard rules file for the app looks like:

```
-dontwarn com.mylibrary.**
-dontwarn org.acra.**
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn com.google.**

-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep class com.mylibrary.** { *; }

-keep class org.acra.** {
    *;
}
```

Edit: For clarification, this is my own library and there are no errors being thrown. Everything builds fine and the app runs as expected, with the exception of the features that the library is supposed to add.

Comment: is it your library or open source ?

Comment: Its my library, not open source.

Comment: does your library have broadcastRecievers ? What happens if you remove all that stuff with the "keep" and use only -keep class !mycode.** { *; }.  BroadcastReceivers cannot be proguarded because the manifest needs to call them so it needs there names. If you need to use broadcastReciever then move your logic into other classes and instanitate them from Reciever.

Comment: Yes it does, in a few places. I'll try that suggestion now.

Comment: try this: -keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver in your current implementation.

Comment: Sorry i cant edit my answer above but BroadcastReciever still will get obfuscated, its just it wont get removed. if you define receiver in manifest only proguard think receiver is not being used and can strip it out.  so we use keep here to tell proguard the reciever will be used.  let me know if keeping the broadcastReceiver resolves your issues

Comment: `-keep class !mycode.** {*;}` worked, but the BroadcastReceiver specific one did not (in the app rules, anyway. The lib already uses something similar in its rules file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there were rules in the app's Proguard rules file that caused the library to get obfuscated once again, breaking functionality. I added a rule to ensure the entire library was skipped during the Proguard process and everything worked itself out.